# Text vs file name as a property

Tags: javascript, gruntjs

I have a property within my grunt plugin that accepts either text or a file name from which the text is to be loaded.

Is there any kind of convention within the grunt system as to how to present such properties within the plugin protocol?

P.S. In my plugin it is likely to be 50/50 when the property will need a text or a file name.

**UPDATE:**

Since I didn't get any answers about a possible convention, I implemented it as follows:

I had two properties - `header` and `footer` that could be either a text or a file name. And since I already had `options:{}` used, I added one more option:

```
options: {
    fileMode: true
}
```

to explicitly indicate that those properties are to be interpreted as file names. When not set, they are considered to contain plain text.

And I implemented that within grunt plugin [grunt-file-wrap](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-file-wrap).

Comment: It might be easier to just accept one or the other, e.g. if you accept the text, the user can load the file contents themself

Comment: @Whymarrh wouldn't manual file loading present a huge inconvenience, as far as the grunt system goes?

Comment: I don't see why it would. Or you could offer two properties (e.g. `textContent` and `filename`) and just use whichever exists, defaulting to the text content if both exist.

Comment: @Whymarrh I really wanted to avoid having extra properties like that, because it is ambiguous when both are used. Anyhow, I updated my question with what I used in the end.

Comment: You might be better off posting your solution as an answer.